# Сканирование из консоли (java)

Tags: java

Пусть в консоли вводят {1, 2, 3, 4}, причем, я не знаю количество чисел, я хочу работать с этим, как с массивом целых чисел, но понятно , что я не могу считать это как массив целых чисел, так как там присутствуют запятые и кавычки, я хотел попробовать считать это как строку, но после пробела считывание прекращается.

Comment: Так вы что хотите, чтобы при вводе "{1, 2, 3, 4}" это сохранялось в стринг? Или вы хотите распарсить введённую строчку просто в массив чисел?

Comment: Сначала сохранить это в стринг, а потом преобразовать в массив чисел

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то должно получиться как-то вот так...

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;  
import java.util.*;

public class MyApp {

    static List<Integer> mynumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "{1, 2, 3, 4}";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while(matcher.find())
            mynumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()));

    }   
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, Ваше решение неправильно работает на следующем инпуте: "{11, 12, 23, 34}". Но вроде бы становится корректным при таком паттерне: "[\\d]+"

Comment: Дело в том, что нельзя считать это как строку сразу, так как там присутствуют пробелы, что воспринимается, как конец ввода строки.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String input = "{1', 2; 3, 4,   5   6, 7}";

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new StringReader(input.replaceAll("[^\\d]+", " ")));

    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
    }
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```